# Change a color of a cell from one cell in sheet2 when making reference to it in sheet1

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I'm trying to change the color of a cell in one sheet when made a reference in another sheet.

`Sheet2` is a list of addresses and I want these to turn red when I use them in the main sheet on `sheet1`.  I have tried conditional formatting but I cannot get it to work with the options that are available.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The formula in conditional formatting can't refer directly to cell/s in a different sheet. However if you give the range in Sheet1 a Workbook name this can be used. Then something like

```
=MATCH(A1,Used,0)
```

with formatting of your choice should suit ('Used' here is the named range).